Steam Deck does not source .bash_profile
From my testing it seems the Steam Deck does not source a .bash_profile or a .profile file inside ~ (by default /home/deck)
After some investigation there is a bash profile deep in the OS which has the following:
───────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: /home/.steamos/offload/root/.bash_profile
───────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ #  SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
   2   │ #
   3   │ #  Copyright © 2020 Collabora Ltd.
   4   │ #  Copyright © 2020 Valve Corporation.
   5   │ #
   6   │ #  This file is part of steamos-image-recipes.
   7   │ #
   8   │ #  steamos-image-recipes is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   9   │ #  it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published
  10   │ #  by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
  11   │ #  (at your option) any later version.
  12   │ 
  13   │ #
  14   │ # ~/.bash_profile
  15   │ #
  16   │ 
  17   │ [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
───────┴──────────────────────────────────

There is also a copy of this file on /etc/skel/.bash_profile
My understanding is that .bash_profile should source .bashrc and not the other way around, but in this case it seems there is no way for me to add a file on the home directory that only gets sourced once and not on every single new shell.
So I have the following questions:

Is my assessment correct or could this be some SteamOS / ArchLinux quirk?
Should I source my aliases and exports on this ~/.bashrc or modify the system files to also source my ~/.bash_profile?

Thanks in advance!

bash --version      5.01.16
konsole --version  23.04.2

Steam LCD model, version: Linux steamdeck 6.1.52-valve16-1-neptune-61


What exactly did your testing consist of?

I added an echo to each file, .bashrc, .bash_profile, .bash_aliases, and saw which ones were being sourced by default. Initially I had a line to source bashrc from bash profile, but since rc was being sourced by itself I could just remove it

And what did your test show, exactly? How was your test conducted, how did you start the shell?

I opened the Konsole application on desktop mode, once from sleep, another from a full power down. What I saw was that differently from the MacOS Terminal application for example, which will only source the  ~/.bash_profile by default, the deck instead was sourcing ~/.bashrc by default, and not sourcing the profile.
Actually I think my previous bash_profile symlink was replaced by an update as well, which could have caused some other sourcing issues

So that's usually configurable from the terminal emulator settings. Your macos terminal is configured to run a login shell, and login shells source .profile or it's equivalent. Most terminal emulators on Linux default to running a non-login shell, which source the rc file instead. Example for GNOME Terminal: https://askubuntu.com/a/598072/158442

Aha! So this is some configuration in the Konsole emulator for KDE Plasma then? I'll have a look, thanks for the explanation


Is my assessment correct or could this be some SteamOS / ArchLinux quirk?

Your assessment is mostly correct. In the Steam Deck case, the situation you observed might be influenced by specific system customizations in SteamOS.
If you need configurations that should only apply to login shells, consider using .bash_profile, but you may need to manually source it in the existing system setup.
This involves editing system files, which might be overwritten by updates and requires caution.

Should I source my aliases and exports on this ~/.bashrc or modify the system files to also source my ~/.bash_profile?

For simplicity and compatibility, place your configuration in .bashrc.
It might be simpler to place your aliases, exports, and other configurations directly into .bashrc

Makes sense, thanks for the help! I'm very wary of messing with the default configs Valve created so this does seem like the best solution
